# DIV within a DIV and padding issue

Tags: html, css

I'd like the header section of my article DIV to take the full width of the DIV and goes up to the top (like on the 2nd picture) but cannot achieve that due the padding of the DIV (see 2nd picture). Is there a workaround? Thanks

http://jsfiddle.net/ph2yq/2/

[image]

What I'd like to achieve:

[image]

HTML:

```
<div class="article">
    <div class="article-headline"><h1>Once upon a time</h1></div>
    <h2>Sub-title</h2><p>Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium, totam rem aperiam, eaque ipsa quae ab illo inventore veritatis et quasi architecto beatae vitae </p>
      </div>
```

CSS:

```
.article {
    clear: right;
    float: right;
    text-align:justify;
    color:#000;
    opacity:1;
    width: 590px;
    padding: 20px 32px 25px 50px;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 15;
    margin-top: 136px;
    /* background: #3B5898; */

    box-shadow:-2px 0 5px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5); 
    overflow: visible;
margin-right: 50px;
/* background-image: url("../images/pagetile.png"); */
    background: #FFF;
bottom:60px;
  /* box-shadow: 0 1px 5px rgba(0,0,0,0.25), 0 0 20px rgba(0,0,0,0.1) inset;
  border-radius: 1%     1%     1%     1% /     1%     1%     1%     1%; */

}


.article p {
    padding-right:20px;
    color: #333;
}
.article-headline {
    background:#03F;
    color: #fff;
    border-right:40px;
    border-right-color:#3F3;
}
.article h1, .article h2 {
    margin-top: -4px;
    padding-bottom: 2px;
}
```

Comment: Why is the h1 in a div?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

NEW CSS:

```
.article-headline {
    background:#03F;
    color: #fff;
    border-right:40px;
    border-right-color:#3F3;
    margin: -20px 0 0 -50px;
    width: 662px;
    padding: 10px 0  0 10px;
}
```

**There is demo: http://jsfiddle.net/ph2yq/2/**

Answer (score 1):

your article contains position relative, so position absolute would work as it relates to the container.

```
.article-headline {
  position:absolute;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  width:100%
}
```

working jsFiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/ph2yq/11/

http://www.developerfusion.com/code/5405/css-positioning-within-a-container/

Answer (score 1):

You may have to adjust some of the padding, but this should get you started. I gave the headline a `position:absolute` and adjusted the top, left and right to get rid of the border.

http://jsfiddle.net/ph2yq/5/

Answer (score 1):

Just play with negative `margin` and `padding` in `.article-headline`:

```
.article-headline {
    background:#03F;
    color: #fff;
    border-right:40px;
    border-right-color:#3F3;
    margin: -20px -32px 10px -50px; // this is relative to .article padding
    padding: 5px 40px 0; // this is relative to this margin
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ph2yq/10/

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, had to clean it up a bit to understand:

http://jsfiddle.net/ph2yq/7/

HTML:

```
<div class="article">
<div class="article-headline"><h1>Once upon a time</h1></div>
<div class="article-body">
<h2>Sub-title</h2>Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium, totam rem aperiam, eaque ipsa quae ab illo inventore veritatis et quasi architecto beatae vitae 
</div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.article-body {
    padding: 20px 32px 25px 50px;
    margin-right: 50px;
}
.article {
    text-align:justify;
    color:#000;
    opacity:1;
    width: 590px;
    z-index: 15;
    box-shadow:-2px 0 5px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5); 
    overflow: visible;
    background: #FFF;
}

.article p {
    padding-right:20px;
    color: #333;
}
.article-headline {
    background:#03F;
    color: #fff;
    border-right:40px;
    border-right-color:#3F3;
    padding-left:30px;
}
.article-headline h1, .article h2 {
    margin-top: -4px;
    padding-bottom: 2px;
}
```

Comment: Thanks - however looks like the fiddle doesn't return the expected result (can't see the headline)

Comment: Hmmm, it shows totally another CSS (I'm not used to this thing). Paste mine from here, it works.